# String[] S in java,add value in it,now create 2 more array,even[]shall contain the values S[] with even index number and odd[] with odd index number

Tags: java, sql, arrays, sql-server

Create a array of String[] S of size x in Java , add some value init , now create two more array even[] and odd[], even array shall contain the values  String S[] with even index number and odd[] will contain values of String S[]  with odd index number

```
package trying;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int val;
        int evcounter = 0;
        int odcounter = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter total no of elements ");
        val = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter values ");
        String[] n = new String[val];
        for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
            n[i] = sc.next();

            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                evcounter++;
            } else {
                odcounter++;
            }

            if (evcounter + odcounter == val) {
                String[] eve = new String[evcounter];
                String[] odd = new String[odcounter];
                System.out.println("******Please Help AFTER THIS**********");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
Enter total no of elements 
3
Enter Values
HI
hello
Bye
Even array:[HI,Bye]
ODD array :[hello]
```

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: You need more than one loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int val;
    int evcounter = 0;
    int odcounter = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter total no of elements ");
    val = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter values ");
    String[] n = new String[val];

    String[] eve = new String[(int) Math.ceil(val/2D)];
    String[] odd = new String[val/2];

    for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        n[i] = sc.next();

        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            eve[evcounter] = n[i];
            evcounter++;
        } else {
            odd[odcounter] = n[i];
            odcounter++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Even array: " + Arrays.toString(eve));
    System.out.println("Odd array: " + Arrays.toString(odd));
}
```

Comment: could you explain  part of code   String[] eve = new String[(int) Math.ceil(val/2D)];
     String[] odd = new String[val/2];

     for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
         n[i] = sc.next();

         if (i % 2 == 0) {
             eve[evcounter] = n[i];
             evcounter++;
         } else {
             odd[odcounter] = n[i];
             odcounter++;
         }

Comment: the count of odd String[] is always val / 2
val / 2D return a double, when val is even it will be x.0 when val is odden it will be x.5
Math.ceil() return normal double when it was x.0 when it was x.5 it's return (x+1).0
then you have to cast the double back to int
Now you have instance of odd and eve before reading from console and you can fill it directly

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int evenCounter = 0;
    int oddCounter = 0;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter total no of elements ");
    int num = reader.nextInt();

    String[] n = new String[num];
    System.out.println("Enter values:");
    for (int i=0;i<n.length;i++)
    {
        n[i]=reader.next();
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            evenCounter++;
        } 
        else 
        {
            oddCounter++;
        }
    }
    String[] even = new String[evenCounter];
    String[] odd = new String[oddCounter];

   for (int z=0;z<n.length;z++)
   {
       if (z%2==0)
       {
           for (int j=0;j<even.length;j++)
           {
               if (even[j]==null)
               {
                   even[j]=n[z];
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
       else if (z%2==1)
       {
           for (int j=0;j<odd.length;j++)
           {
               if (odd[j]==null)
               {
                   odd[j]=n[z];
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

The idea is to iterate over the original String array and check if it's index is 
even/odd(like you did in your code to check how many odds/evens there are).
if the index is even you go over the evens array and check for the first empty cell of the array (in java when you generate a string array you get an array full of nulls so you search for the first null and replace it with the value from the original array).
and the same about odds.

Comment: unable to Sysout the even and Odd arrays , getting garbage  values

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 1.8+ then better to use functional style which is much easy to understand and elegant.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.IntPredicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class MyTestCase {

  @Test
  public void evenOddStringArrayPrinting() {

    String[] src = new String[] {"HI", "Hello", "Bye"};
    final String[] evenArray = getArrayFrom(src, i -> i % 2 == 0);
    final String[] oddArray = getArrayFrom(src, i -> i % 2 == 1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(evenArray));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(oddArray));
    Assert.assertEquals(2, evenArray.length);
    Assert.assertEquals(1, oddArray.length);

  }

  private String[] getSome(final String[] src, final IntPredicate predicate) {
    return IntStream.range(0, src.length)
        .filter(predicate)
        .mapToObj(i -> src[i])
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .toArray(new String[] {});
  }
}
```